# AADSTS50011 Error when trying to login to my react native app using Azure AD

Tags: react-native, authentication, oauth, azure-active-directory, microsoft-account

I have an issue when I tried to use my code that I found on expo go website using Azure AD on react native to let users login with a Microsoft Account. However, whenever I tried to login with a test account into the app, it will encounter an error as shown in the picture below:

[image: AADSTS50011 Error code when I tried to login with Microsoft Account]

[image: Screenshot of Azure AD Redirect URI I configured]

Every time I tried to test the login, it will show that error code and says that the redirect URI specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for my app.

Another question I have is whether this code can work even after I push it out to the Google Play and App Stores. If not, can you show an example of a login code for Microsoft Account that works even after I push it to the Google Play and App Stores? Thanks.

The code I used below:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import {
  exchangeCodeAsync,
  makeRedirectUri,
  useAuthRequest,
  useAutoDiscovery,
} from 'expo-auth-session';
import { Button, Text, SafeAreaView, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';


WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

export default function Login() {
  // Endpoint
  const discovery = useAutoDiscovery(
    'https://login.microsoftonline.com/my_tenant_id/v2.0',
  );
  const redirectUri = makeRedirectUri({
    scheme: 'native',
    path: 'exp://nz-aqv.kimx.app-test.exp.direct:80/--/exp://nz-aqv.kimx.app-test.exp.direct:80/--auth', // The link that I got from copying the login page link and extracting the link but it does not work
  });
  const clientId = 'my_client_id';

  // We store the JWT in here
  const [token, setToken] = React.useState(null);   

  // Request
  const [request, , promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId,
      scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'offline_access'],
      redirectUri,
    },
    discovery,
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight, paddingLeft: 5, paddingRight: 5}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color:'blue', marginBottom: 10, textAlign: 'center'}}>Welcome to SSMC Mobile App! Click the button to Login.</Text>
      <Button color='purple
      '
        disabled={!request}
        title="Login"
        onPress={() => {
          promptAsync().then((codeResponse) => {
            if (request && codeResponse?.type === 'success' && discovery) {
              exchangeCodeAsync(
                {
                  clientId,
                  code: codeResponse.params.code,
                  extraParams: request.codeVerifier
                    ? { code_verifier: request.codeVerifier }
                    : undefined,
                  redirectUri,
                },
                discovery,
              ).then((res) => {
                setToken(res.accessToken);
              });
            }
          });
        }}
      />
      <Text>{token}</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

I have tried going to the website stated in the troubleshooting details section of the page to find out the link of the login page, extract it out and put into my code and azure AD redirect URI but it did not work.

Here's the URL that I'm using to get the authentication process from the url:

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?code_challenge=_ZcgLdpFvHvZmU3RY5H7-Imli57IdWFKyxDS97AJgjY&code_challenge_method=S256&redirect_uri=exp%3A%2F%2Fnz-aqv.kimx.app-test.exp.direct%3A80%2F--%2Fexp%3A%2F%2Fnz-aqv.kimx.app-test.exp.direct%3A80%2F--%2Fexp%3A%2F%2Fnz-aqv.kimx.app-test.exp.direct%3A80%2F--auth&client_id={app_id}&response_type=code&state=duOkQiYXAF&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20offline_access](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?code_challenge=_ZcgLdpFvHvZmU3RY5H7-Imli57IdWFKyxDS97AJgjY&code_challenge_method=S256&redirect_uri=exp%3A%2F%2Fnz-aqv.kimx.app-test.exp.direct%3A80%2F--%2Fexp%3A%2F%2Fnz-aqv.kimx.app-test.exp.direct%3A80%2F--%2Fexp%3A%2F%2Fnz-aqv.kimx.app-test.exp.direct%3A80%2F--auth&client_id=%7Bapp_id%7D&response_type=code&state=duOkQiYXAF&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20offline_access)

Comment: Could you paste the screenshot of the redirect URL you configured in the portal? Go to Azure AD Application -> Authentication -> Check your redirect URL matches the URL you are passing in the request

Comment: The redirect URL in the [**Portal**](https://i.imgur.com/cscZ3ek.png) must match

Comment: Ok I have added a screenshot of the azure AD redirect URL to the question @Rukmini, it was accepted by azure AD so I thought that it would work.

Comment: If you want to use PKCE flow then configure  the redirect URL under SPA platform

Comment: Oh, I see what is PKCE? I thought react native with expo go is for mobile app? And also just to clarify, after I finish development of the app and push it to Google Play and App store, the login should still work right?

Comment: Oh, I see I just tried putting the URL on the SPA configuration and it says "Wildcard characters, HTTP scheme not allowed"

Comment: Yes check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/reply-url

Comment: @Rukmini I have read that document but I am not sure how to make my link compatible since it does not start with https, can you advice me on what to do?